# How do I install dialog utility on Fedora Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, dialog, fedora, utility

I tried this code on CLI -

yum provides */dialog

It doesn't seem to work. I also tried a link for RPM but that didn't work either.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Please show evidence of what research you have done.  Please include a link to any resources you found to be of (relevant) interest.  Please indicate what error messages you are getting or if you are getting no error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current (past year or so) Fedora uses `dnf`.  Either way, you would use "install":

```
sudo yum install dialog
sudo dnf install dialog
```